# What exactly does it mean to "register" a variable

Tags: php, global-variables, superglobals, register-globals

This is regarding the PHP global variables. Does it mean the global variables are simply assigned values through the HTTP request(ie: Varaibles where pre-existing but without values), or that the variables are "instantiated" and assigned values(ie: variable where not pre-existing in script)?
I am yet to see any text which explains.

Comment: Do you mean `register_globals`?

Comment: @arxanas yes, register_globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `register_globals` will create the appropriate global variables and assign values to them.  Note that it's probably a really bad idea to use `register_globals`, since it poses a security risk.  It's better to use the superglobal arrays `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: thanks, my question applies to superglobals too. So is it the same process(create and assign values) for both types of variables besides superglobals being more secure?

Comment: There are only a handful of superglobals, and they all exist whenever PHP runs.  You cannot create your own superglobals AFAIK, they're precreated by PHP for you every time.

Comment: yes, I meant "create and assign" by the system, not by myself.

Answer (score 1):

`register`ing globals simply means the process of registering various request variables as globally available. However, "register" in this case differs fundamentally from "assign" or "set" because the globals are inherently linked to their superglobal key counterparts (or "registered" as an alias), perhaps best summarized by this snippet of code:

```
// register_globals is on
$_POST["username"] === $username; // true

$username = "foo";
$_POST["username"] === $username; // *still* true

$_POST["username"] = "bar";
$_POST["username"] === $username; // *still* true
```

That is, changing one will change the corresponding superglobal key. Of course, this behavior should not be relied upon — if you're using `register_globals` in the first place, you're doing something wrong.